# Apache2 & .htaccess : Apache ignoring AccessFile

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.2, .htaccess

Hi there here is my server configuration:

DEBIAN 32Bits / PHP 5 / Apache

> Server version: Apache/2.2.3 
>   - Server built:   Mar 22 2008 09:29:10

The AccessFiles :

> grep -ni AccessFileName *

```
apache2.conf:134:AccessFileName .htaccess
apache2.conf:667:AccessFileName .httpdoverride
```

All the AllowOverride statements in my apache2/ folder.

```
mods-available/userdir.conf:6:                AllowOverride Indexes AuthConfig Limit
mods-available/userdir.conf:16:               AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
mods-enabled/userdir.conf:6:                AllowOverride Indexes AuthConfig Limit
mods-enabled/userdir.conf:16:               AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
sites-enabled/default:8:        AllowOverride All
sites-enabled/default:14:           AllowOverride All
sites-enabled/default:19:   AllowOverride All
sites-enabled/default:24:       AllowOverride All
sites-enabled/default:42:        AllowOverride All
```

The sites-enabled/default file :

```
  1 <VirtualHost *>
  2         ServerAdmin admin@site.com
  3         ServerName mysite.com
  4         ServerAlias mysite.com 
  5         DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/
  6         <Directory />
  7                 Options FollowSymLinks
  8                 AllowOverride All
  9                 Order Deny,Allow
 10                 Deny from all
 11         </Directory>
 12         <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/>
 13                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 14                 AllowOverride All
 15                 Order allow,deny
 16                 allow from all
 17         </Directory>
 18         <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/test/>
 19         AllowOverride All
 20         </Directory>
 21 
 22         ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
 23         <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
 24                 AllowOverride All
 25                 Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 26                 Order allow,deny
 27                 Allow from all
 28         </Directory>
 29 
 30         ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
 31 
 32         # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 33         # alert, emerg.
 34         LogLevel warn
 35 
 36         CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
 37         ServerSignature Off
 38 
 39     Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
 40     <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
 41         Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
 42         AllowOverride All
 43         Order deny,allow
 44         Deny from all
 45         Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
 46     </Directory>
 47 
 48 
 49 
 50 
 51 
 52 
 53 
 54 </VirtualHost>
```

If i change any Allow from all in Deny from all , it works whenever i put it.

I've got one .htaccess at /mysite.com/.htaccess & one at /mysite.com/test/.htaccess
with:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Neither of them work i can still see my website. I've got mod_rewrite enabled but i don't think it does anything here.

I've tried almost everything :/ It works on my local environnement (MAMP) but fails when on my Debian server.

Comment: Simple question! Did you try to restart/reload your apache server? You did not mention that in your question!

Comment: I did. At each modifications

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess files can interact with the main config in unobvious ways. In your case your problem is that you have access control bot in your httpd.conf and your .htaccess file. And they get both applied.

You have in your config:

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

And in your .htaccess file:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

So the end result is as if the permissions are:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny From All
Allow From ALL
```

Which means that everyone gets access. In this case you should use "Order Allow, Deny".

You should however not use .htaccess files at all if you have access to the main config. .htaccess files exist as a workaround for cases where you don't have the right to edit the main config (like shared hosting) but if you can edit the main config you should use that.

.htaccess files have a lot of disadvantages. They are only read at request time, and only after the server has translated the URL to a file system resource. They are not read when the server startes. This means that the .htaccess files are possibly read at every request (causing a performance hit), but sometimes not read ever.

Answer (score -1):

I think when you are using deny from all in your root directory, you are blocking all, also your localhost.
You need to put localhost allow in your root.

```
<Directory /> 
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All  
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
<Directory>
```

Then, reload and restart apache: 
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
For reference and performance, look at apache documentation for [htaccess](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=htaccess+allowoverride#hl=en&&sa=X&ei=0f8gTY_oNIqr8AaO8JDgDQ&ved=0CBEQBSgA&q=apache2+htaccess+allowoverride&spell=1&fp=ded5a2edbb6a28fc) and [authorization](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html)

Comment: I don't think this is the issue here. You don't want access to / for anyone. Not even localhost.